# Associative array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript

How would I declare/hard code the following dictionary in js?

```
var rooms = new Dictionary<string, List<Room>>
{
    {
        "Single room", new List<Room>
        {
            new Room
            {
                Caption = "Single room1",
                Price = "12.--"
            },
            new Room()
            {
                Caption = "Single room2",
                Price = "12.--"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Double room", new List<Room>
        {
            new Room
            {
                Caption = "Double room1",
                Price = "12.--"
            },
            new Room()
            {
                Caption = "Double room2",
                Price = "12.--"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Appears this sample is too long for SO so I add some more text here. This shouldn't be too difficult, I just can't wrap my head around it and it's such a concise question, I though I post it here.

Comment: `Dictionary` -> `Object` literal, `List` -> `Array`, `Room` -> Custom function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrays for lists, objects for classes:

```
var rooms = {

    "Single room": [
        {
            Caption: "Single room1",
            Price: "12.--"
        },
        {
            Caption: "Single room2",
            Price: "12.--"
        }
    ],
    "Double room": [
        {
            Caption: "Double room1",
            Price: "12.--"
        },
        {
            Caption: "Double room2",
            Price: "12.--"
        }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var rooms = {
    'Single room': [
        { 'caption': 'Single room1', 'price': '12.--' }
        { 'caption': 'Single room2', '12.--' }
    ],
    'Double room': [
        { 'caption': 'Double room1', 'price': '12.--' }
        { 'caption': 'Double room2', '12.--' }
    ]
};
```